# How to make jquery.ajax to fire success or error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to take a JSON from a PHP script, with this code:

```
var myUrl = "http://....er.com";

function getJson() {
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: myUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 3000,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (respJSON) {
        console.log("OK");

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("NOTOK");
        }

    });
}
```

The URL succesfully returns a valid JSON when I look at the browser:

```
{"RESPONSE_CODE" : "OK","RESPONSE_MESSAGE" : [{"id" : "9","denominazione" : "ADV0001","lat" : "0","lng" : "0","idTerritorio" : "1","idCRM" : "MOVENTU"}]}
```

But I don't get why the log in my console is not the "OK" log neither the "NOTOK" log, instead, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loader' of undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the object you're passing to `.ajax()`, you'll likely want the url to be a string; also don't forget the comma. Like: `url: http://localhost/sfm/backend.php,`

Comment: Your url looks incorrect. Is should be valid string url.

Comment: you are right,but in the code i'm using a var i changed it for the sensible data, but the var is correct in my code i'm going to edit the question

Comment: Have you tried jsonp for cross domain requests?

Comment: What platform are you working on? It seems the "loader" things is outside of the jQuery Ajax problem

Comment: Please remove dataType "json" and try